# The result of expression is always true since value of type "double" is is never equal to null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, nullable, c#-8.0

I am trying exclude those records which are null.

// I cant change datatype in sql server
SQL Column Name with Datatype : RMU : Float

Model class with Datatype :

```
 [Column(TypeName = "float")]
 public double RMU { get; set; }
```

LINQ -->

```
var RMUNotNullCheck = DB1.tblImport.Where(x => x.RPU != null).ToList();
```

The above code gives me warning since double can not be null and there are few records which are kept null and I dont need that.

How to get rid of those records which are null please tell.

Comment: Why not use `double?` for `RMU`?

Comment: I have tried but on updating Model its giving me error so is there any work around or anything else I can do in C# code.

Comment: @ShanuGarg Add that error to the question

Comment: It looks like you are using LINQ to databases, but don't say which: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? Also, which database provider?

Comment: @NishānWickramarathna Read properly it is warning not error.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the RMU property a `Nullable<T>` and then check for `null` in LINQ.

```
public double? Rmu { get; set;} 
...
...
var rmuWithoutNull = DB1.tblImport.Where(x => x.Rmu != null).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only compare an double to NULL if the double is [nullable value type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types). If not, the default value for double will be 0 and never null.

You can define a nullable double property like this:

```
double? value = null;
```

So in your case it's

```
public double? RMU { get; set; }
```

And your code should work fine.